# Why can't I return an implementation of an interface for a method that requests the interface?

Tags: java, interfaces, iterator

I am implementing an interface I on a class A.
Class A implements I.

I have an Iterator T that is supposed to return an object which implements I everytime I call next.

My iterator goes as follows (of course omitting other stuff):

```
public class T<I> implements Iterator<I> {        
    @Override
    public I next() {
        return new A();
    }    
}
```

However, I get this error: Required I, found A (for the return new A() line)....

I don't know what is happening. Can someone help me?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)**

Comment: ...[Hint: Programmers.SE don't do coding help and expect research before asking](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21680/279150)

Comment: You have to cast `A` to `I` for this code to work.  `return new (I)A();`

Comment: You are asking us to take your word for the claim that `A` implements `I`. Please show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class definition introduces I as a type variable, meaning that it does not refer to the interface you expect it to. Change your class definition to

```
public class T implements Iterator <I>
```

and everything should work fine.